# UIFontDescriptor can't find iOS font

Tags: ios, swift, uifontdescriptor

I am trying to use Avenir Next on a NSAttributedString w/ UIFontDescriptor. It is an in-built iOS font. It works in my SwiftUI components but if I try to create a custom UIFontDescriptor it doesn't find the font and defaults to SFUI. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```swift
// descriptor shows font as SFUI
let boldDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor(fontAttributes: [
    UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.family: "Avenir Next",
    UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.traits: [
        UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.weight: UIFont.Weight.bold
    ]
])
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code (as text) showing what you have tried.

Comment: Here you go - standard stuff

Comment: Now show how you attempt to use that descriptor. You need to post sufficient code to reproduce your issue. Creating a `UIFont` from the descriptor code you posted correctly results in a font using Avenir Next.

Comment: Printing it on my machine shows SFUI. Hmm indeed!

Comment: @Nathanael - you'll need to provide some more detail on how you are using that. This quick test: https://pastebin.com/ys4y7Xvw produces this output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLHMw.png

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, How you are using this descriptor method.

[Avenir Next](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/) is an in-built iOS font, but it may not be available on all devices. Make sure the font is installed on the device you are testing on.
Check **font** is available by using the `UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: "Avenir Next")` method to get a list of available font names for the **Avenir Next** family.

```
var fonts: String = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: "Avenir Next")
print(fonts) // ["AvenirNext-Regular", "AvenirNext-Italic", "AvenirNext-UltraLight", "AvenirNext-UltraLightItalic", "AvenirNext-Medium", "AvenirNext-MediumItalic", "AvenirNext-DemiBold", "AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", "AvenirNext-Bold", "AvenirNext-BoldItalic", "AvenirNext-Heavy", "AvenirNext-HeavyItalic"]
```

I also created a new project for `boldDescriptor` method & it is working fine in my case.
Use this project [Demo Project for UIFontDescriptor -
GitHub](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/Stackoverflow-Issue-UIFontDescriptor) & let me know if this example doesn't work for you.

Output:
[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLOv6.png)

Also, you can import font from the system into the project.

Please also check the following reasons:

- Make sure your System is up to date because many of the Catalina users suffered from this issue.
- Make sure you're using `iOS 13` or greater version for testing the fonts. [Note on official website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/futr4.png)
- Make sure the required font is available in the **Font Book**. [Search by Font Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrV2g.png) or [Search by folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNyzv.png).
- It is unlikely that fonts would just "stop working" on their own. More likely, there is an issue with the operating system upgrade, or the font databases and caches have been damaged during the upgrade process. It is also important to only have one font manager installed on your Mac at a time, as using multiple font managers can lead to conflicts and damage to the underlying font databases and caches. If you are experiencing issues with fonts not working properly, you may need to try repairing or rebuilding the font databases and caches.
- You should be able to resolve any duplicate fonts if available in your system and ensure that only the necessary fonts are installed and active. [Resolve Duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a05G.png)